# AWK if last field equals

Tags: if-statement, awk

I've done considerable searching and I'm getting frustrated. I'm trying have conditional response on the last field of a file that has dynamic number of fields. I've tried reworking the field separator, but that's been unsuccessful.

It prints the correct field when I use `awk '{print $(NF)}'`

I attempted to do something like this:

`'{ if ($(NF) ~ /LTO/); print $NF}'`

but all fields are returning true. I suspect that the variable substitution in the if statement is not returning the value I want it to.

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] your question to include the missing concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use the editor's `{}` button for format your input, output, and code. Don't tell us "something like" what you have attempted, instead tell us exactly what you have attempted.

Answer (score 3):

```
{if ($(NF) ~ /LTO/); print $NF}
                   ^
                   |
                   |____  Here is your problem.  Your if statement has
                          no effect on the subsequent print.  Remove ;
```

of course idiomatic way of writing this is

```
$NF~/LTO/{print $NF}
```